# Google Places API: Using Multiple Name Parameters in the Places Search

Tags: api, google-maps-api-3

I've been reading the documentation at: http://code.google.com/intl/nl/apis/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceSearches

But How do I modify the Place Search Request (shown below) so that I can limit the results to specific businesses only.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyAiFpFd85eMtfbvmVNEYuNds5TEF9FjIPI
```

For example in the above code it has**types=food&name=harbour** as two of the parameters.  How can I include just "bakery" and "cafe" (both are supported list types) as the types parameter and then include multiple name parameters as well.

In bigger cities it may come back with 20 or so results, but I want to limit it to a handful of businesses that I have agreements with and just show their names on the map.  I don't want Starbucks to come back so I want to restrict it to just the 8-10 businesses that I have the agreements with.  Their names will be stored in a database so I can easily retrieve them and pass them into the HTTP URL, but I don't know how to do multiple names and get them all to show up on the map at the same time.

Any links to tutorials that can help or your ideas and suggestions would greatly help!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Im doing pretty much the same thing now and i was wondering if you did find a solution?

Comment: i found it difficult to do what i needed it to do using the place search request.  i had to take a new approach.  i basically started my own db of locations and had to abandon the api specifically for a search.  sorry i couldn't help!

Comment: Thats fine. That's what i am planning to do as well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include types "bakery" and "cafe" by modifying your request parameter types=food|bakery|cafe add more types  separate by "|"  operator
for supported type list refer [Link](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/supported_types.html)

Comment: This is good for the "type" parameter but not for the "name" parameter which does not fully work with pipes.